# En Linux, es posible que un fólder tenga permisos de grupo de sólo lectura, pero que un archivo específico dentro del fólder los tenga de escritura?

Tags: linux, archivo, seguridad, permisos

Supóngase que la carpeta FOLDER contiene Archivo1.txt Archivo2.txt ... Archivo1000.txt. Cómo asignar los permisos de lectura/escritura para que GRUPO1 tenga permiso de sólo lectura sobre FOLDER pero particularmente sobre Archivo17.txt los tenga de lectura/escritura ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres haciendo cambios en varias etapas.

Para cambiar de grupo *FOLDER* a *GRUPO1* junto con todos su contenido:

`chown -R :GRUPO1 FOLDER`

Para modificar el acceso de *FOLDER* para que *GRUPO1* tenga permiso de sólo  lectura:

`chmod g+rx FOLDER/`

Se ve raro que se le agrega el permiso de ejecución pero los directorios lo necesitan para poder hacer búsquedas dentro de ellos, lo que también es lectura.

Luego hay que cambiar los contenidos de *FOLDER* para que también sean de sólo lectura:

`chmod g=r FOLDER/*`

Y finalmente, para cambiar los permisos de *Archivo17.txt* a modo lectura/escritura

`chmod g+rw FOLDER/Archivo17.txt`

Ahora puedes probarlo cambiando de usuario (uno que esté dentro de *GRUPO1*) y confirmar que:

- puedes leer el contenido de *FOLDER* `ls FOLDER`
- puedes leer cualquier archivo `cat FOLDER/Archivo 1.txt`
- puedes modificar *Archivo17.txt* `echo "hola mundo" >> FOLDER/Archivo17.txt`
- no puedes modificar otros archivos `echo "hola de nuevo" >> FOLDER/Archivo2.txt`

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.